# Return Resource instead of Model using laravel with

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel 8, I have a model with `belongsTo` relationship with another.

```
class Author extends Model
{}
```

And another one,

```
class Post extends Model
{
   public function author()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author', 'author_id');
   }
 }


// Controller
Post::with('author');
```

By using `with` I can retrieve the author based on Post. However, all attributes from author are retrieved. I don't want to return all fields since an author may have a confidential info.

If I have multiple table to get `with(['model1', 'model2'...])`, this returns all foreign table fields.

Is there a way like, `with(new AuthorResource())` so I can put logic into the resource like restrictions to fields to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a PostResource, add an author field in an array, and pass the author resource over there.

```
  return [
        'author' => AuthorResource::make($this->author)
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks. I just modified it on my part since I am using a Pipeline,

`return [
        'author' => new AuthorResource($this->whenLoaded('author'))
 ];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Select.

```
Post::with('author')->select('author.id')->get();
```

Comment: Though this answers the question for Post but the question is referring to the fields from author table. If I have multiple table to get `with(['model1', 'model2'...])`, this can't return the exact foreign table data.

Is there a way like, `with(new AuthorResource())` so I can put logic into the resource like restrictions?